# A problem about an unramified prime in a Galois extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois extension of degree $n$, we will denote its ring of integers by $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be an arbitrary prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$, which is unramified over $\mathbb{Z}$, and prime to $n!$. We will denote the residue field of $\mathfrak{p}$ by $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$, its characteristics by $p$, and its residue degree by $f$. Let $x \in \mathcal{O}_K$, and let $\bar{x}$ be its image in $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$.
and assume that $P \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a monic minimal polynomial of $\bar{x}$, such that $P(x) \in \mathfrak{p} \backslash \mathfrak{p}^2$, and $\deg(P)=f$.

(Q): Show that $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^2$ is generated by the image of $x$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$.

---

My attempts: Since $P$ have the minimal degree, among the polynomials which are vanishing $x$ module $\mathfrak{p}$, then it should be irreducible over the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.
Therefore $1, x, \cdots, x^{f-1}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}/p$.
Also, notice that  $$\dfrac{\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}}{P(X)} \equiv \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}} \oplus x \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}} \oplus \cdots \oplus x^{f-1}\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$$
is a field between $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\dfrac{\mathcal{O}_K}{\mathfrak{p}}$, with $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$-degree equal to $f=[\dfrac{\mathcal{O}_K}{\mathfrak{p}}:\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}]$, so it should equal to $\dfrac{\mathcal{O}_K}{\mathfrak{p}}$. So we can conclude that $\dfrac{\mathcal{O}_K}{\mathfrak{p}}$ is generated by the image of $x$ over $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$. (My proof on this fact, may contain extra details; if so let me know please.) **But** I don't have any idea why $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^2$ is generated by the image of $x$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$?

> I'm looking to figure out how, in this case, "the assumption $P(x) \in \mathfrak{p} \backslash \mathfrak{p}^2$" helps me solve the problem. I have this issue with similar problems; for instance, I had trouble dealing with **exercises 19-22 from chapter $4$ of Marcus's Number Fields**. (In these exercises I had to deal with "the assumption $\pi \in Q \backslash Q^2$".) Also, I tried to look for some versions of Nakayama's lemma, but I was not succeded.

Comment: @reuns I am not sure, but I think the statement in the question is correct, and $P=X(X-1)$ is not a minimal polynomial for $x=3$. Could you please introduce me a **reference** to read in detail about this fact: "If $p$ is unramified, then $x$ generates $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ algebra, iff it generates $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^m$ as a $\mathbb{Z}/(p^m)$ algebra." Maybe this fact is a keypoint to the problem, and I think this is a very good clue. Thank you so much for your fruitful comment.

Comment: Sure, I missed the 'minimal polynomial' part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one of the main theorems about Dedekind domains that $\mathfrak{p}$ becomes principal $ = (\pi)$ in $O_{K,p}$ thus in $O_K/(\mathfrak{p}^m)$.

$\pi$ can be chosen to be any element of $\mathfrak{p}\setminus \mathfrak{p}^2$.

With $S\subset O_K/(\pi^m)$ a set of representatives of $O_K/(\pi)$ then $$O_K/(\pi^m) = \{ \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} s_j \pi^j,s_j\in S\}$$

$\quad$ (given any element $a\in \pi^j O_K/\pi^m O_K$ there is a unique $s_j\in S$ such that $a-s_j\pi^j\in \pi^{j+1} O_K/\pi^m O_K$)

In your question $\pi= P(x)$ and the set $S$ is taken in the subalgebra generated by $x$, from that $x$ generates $O_K/\mathfrak{p}$ as a $Z/(p)$ algebra (if it was smaller then $x$'s $Z/(p)$-minimal polynomial would be of degree $<f$)

**no need that $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified**.

Comment: Thank you so many dear @reuns (1) "given any element $a\in \pi^j O_K/\pi^m O_K$ there is a unique $s_j\in S$ such that $a-s_j\times\pi^j\in \pi^{j+1} O_K/\pi^m O_K$", I think here there is a typo which missed "$\times\pi^j$" in the phrase "$a-s_j\times\pi^j$". (2): I realized everything in your proof, except the last paragraph ["In your question $\pi= P(x)$ and ..."].

Comment: (3): I learned too much from you dear @reuns , but yet I am not able to prove this fact: "If $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified, then $x$ generates $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ algebra, iff it generates $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^m$ as a $\mathbb{Z}/(p^m)$ algebra." Could you please introduce me a **reference** to read about this fact?

Comment: Yes it is $a-s_j \pi^j$. When unramified, take $\pi= p$ and replace $S$ by $\sum_{i=0}^{f-1} x^i \Bbb{Z}/(p)$, from $O_K/(\pi^m) = \{ \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} s_j \pi^j,s_j\in S\}$ you get $O_K/\mathfrak{p}^m = \sum_{i=0}^{f-1} x^i \Bbb{Z}/(p^m)$

Comment: dear @reuns I can not understand it yet